# Data extraction from the NVD data feed and cpe_match meaning

Tags: java, security

My IT product has CPE defined, for example:
`cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_vista:6.0:sp1:~-~home_premium~-~x64~-`

I am using NVD Data Feed to get all publicly known vulnerabilities.
CVEs are given in .json file and under each CVE item there is a **configurations** node.
If I want to check if my CPE exists in the current CVE item I guess I have to check configurations node, but I am not sure what is the purpose of the           "operator" : "OR", "vulnerable" : false.

Can I just compare my CPE with cpe23Uri or I have to somehow consider *operators* and *vulnerable* nodes as well?

```
"configurations" : {
  "CVE_data_version" : "4.0",
  "nodes" : [ {
    "operator" : "AND",
    "children" : [ {
      "operator" : "OR",
      "cpe_match" : [ {
        "vulnerable" : true,
        "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:adobe:flash_player:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
        "versionStartIncluding" : "10.3",
        "versionEndExcluding" : "10.3.183.19"
      }, {
        "vulnerable" : true,
        "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:a:adobe:flash_player:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
        "versionStartIncluding" : "11.2",
        "versionEndIncluding" : "11.2.202.233"
      } ]
    }, {
      "operator" : "OR",
      "cpe_match" : [ {
        "vulnerable" : false,
        "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:apple:mac_os_x:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
      }, {
        "vulnerable" : false,
        "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:linux:linux_kernel:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
      }, {
        "vulnerable" : false,
        "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
      } ]
    } ]
  }]
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what information you're trying to determine. Notice that the "OR" operator in the lower half of the node only applies between those three items, which together are "AND"ed with the top half. The skeletal structure of the node in question is:

```
"operator" : "AND",
  "children" : [ {
    "operator" : "OR",
    "cpe_match" : [ {
      ...
    } ]
  }, {
    "operator" : "OR",
    "cpe_match" : [ {
      ...
    } ]
  } ]
```

(I have reindented because the "children" node is logically within "AND" even though they are structurally on the same level.)

In other words, two `cpe23Uri`s need to be matched to meet the condition described by this node: any one from the top half AND any one from the bottom half. Your Windows example would appear to match only the latter, and it would not be matching the vulnerable component of your system. To determine whether your system is vulnerable you would need to look for a component that matches a vulnerable item *as well*.